# Using DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=true found 57 vulnerabilities (54 moderate, 3 high) error in webdriverio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, webdriver-io, browser-automation, allure

Hello I am new to webdriverio, and I was trying to run the command

```
DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=true npm i
```

and than after I am getting the following error

```
npm WARN @hint/hint-amp-validator@2.10.11 requires a peer of hint@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN allure-mochajs@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of mocha@^5.2.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-standard@13.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@>=6.0.1 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN wdio-chromedriver-service@6.0.4 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^6.0.0 but none 
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN wdio-mochawesome-reporter@4.0.0 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^5.8.4 but none 
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN wdio-mochawesome-reporter@4.0.0 requires a peer of mochawesome-report- 
generator@^3.1.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN cnn-content-hub-automation@ No repository field.
npm WARN cnn-content-hub-automation@ No license field.

audited 1875 packages in 12.786s
found 57 vulnerabilities (54 moderate, 3 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

### Detect ChromeDriver Version

At times the NPM package version may not be always compatible to your [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version. To get the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) that corresponds to the version of Chrome installed, you can use the npm config property `detect_chromedriver_version`.

```
npm install chromedriver --detect_chromedriver_version
```

Or add property into your `.npmrc` file.

```
detect_chromedriver_version=true
```

Another option is to use environment variable **`DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION`**.

```
DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=true npm install chromedriver
```

> Note: When the property `detect_chromedriver_version` is provided, `chromedriver_version` and `chromedriver_filepath` properties are ignored.

---

### Solution

Instead of:

```
DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=true npm i
```

You need to use:

```
DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=true npm install chromedriver
```